# What is the correct way to output compiled target in a different folder than dependencies DLLs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions, solution

I have a Visual Studio solution file with a few projects (mostly C++),
most of them are configured in a pretty standard way, with Output directory set to a "bin" directory.
Some of them need their primary output target to be outputted to a sub-directory of "bin" (i.e. "bin\others"), but with all their DLL dependencies (managed as NuGet packages) still copied to "bin" directory.
(dependencies DLLs must be in \bin because "others" projects are DLLs loaded at runtime by an EXE in \bin, so dependencies must be found in the EXE path)

The output paths structure looks like the following:

```
\bin (main EXE and ALL dependencies DLLs)  
\bin\others (others projects, with their dependencies DLL in \bin)
```

What I've tried so far:

1. change $(OutDir) for "others" projects, but this does not work because all NuGet dependencies will also be copied to the same output directory.
2. keep $(OutDir) to \bin, but change the "others" projects TargetName to "others\$(ProjectName)", but this causes errors when rebuilding from clean (i.e. in automated build), because MSBuild (actually Microsoft.CppClean.targets file
   included by default in VC++ projects) tries to write to a  "$(IntDir)$(TargetName).Build.CppClean.log", which does not exist (because "$(IntDir)\others\" directory has not been created yet).

I'd like to avoid post-build actions because cmd like commands have problems with parallel automated build via MSBuild, and MSBuild tasks inside projects must be maintained manually (VS IDE does not suppert them, AFAIK).

Any idea or suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: It is a very, *very* bad practice.  Not just because of the build problem, you have not explained how you are going to solve the next problem.  The OS doesn't stand much of a chance to find dependencies in that "others" folder, it is not going to look there.  Good Q+A needs to specify that detail as well.

Comment: @HansPassant Not sure to understand your point, but on Windows, if you launch your EXE (in "bin" folder), that dinamically loads DLLS from "bin\others" folder, dependencies will be correctly found in "bin", that's why I need them to stay there, not in "bin\others".

Answer (score 0):

Default dll search path includes directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable ([MSDN: standard search order for desktop applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx#standard_search_order_for_desktop_applications)).

You could consider adding required path to the PATH variable in the debug environment "Configuration Properties->Debugging->Environment". Something like: "PATH=$PATH;$(SolutionDir)\bin\others".

Comment: It's a good advice, but unfortunately in my case I need the dependency DLLs to stay in \bin\, qhere the EXE is, also for other reasons (the "others" directory needs to contain "others" projects output only (DLLs).